# CMake: undefined reference to `_sbrk' in cross-compile arm project

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, arm

I am trying to convert an uvproj to a CMake project. This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
# CMake minimum version
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)

# Project Infomation
project( Target )
enable_language(ASM)
enable_language(C)

# Reset output path
set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set (LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

# STDLIB
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS)

# Set include path
include_directories (./Src)
include_directories (C:/Users/Laslo/Development/cpp/hbrs-praktikum/OpenRoboticBoard/Firmware)
include_directories (C:/Users/Laslo/Development/cpp/hbrs-praktikum/OpenRoboticBoard/Middleware/Src)

# The need build source path and build all files
set (SRC_FILE0 ./Lib/entry.cpp)
set (SRC_FILE1 ./Lib/main.cpp)
set (SRC_FILE2 ./Src/Application.h)

# CFLAGS
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-g -Wextra -Wshadow -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -Wall -Wundef -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 " CACHE INTERNAL "c compiler flags")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}  -D USE_UART  -D STM32F405xx  -D  __ARM_STM32F405__  -D  _HSE_CLK=8000  -D  _HSE_BYPASS_OFF  -D  HSE_VALUE=8000000  -D HSI_VALUE=8000000  -D _KEIL ")

# CXXFLAGS
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wextra -Wshadow -Wredundant-decls  -Weffc++ -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -Wall -Wundef -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 " CACHE INTERNAL "cxx compiler flags")

# ASMFLAGS
set (CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "-g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 " CACHE INTERNAL "asm compiler flags")

# LDFLAGS
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-g -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=Target.map -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 " CACHE INTERNAL "executable linker flags")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/stm32f4xx_gcc.ld -L ")

#set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -specs=nano.specs")

# Generate the target
add_executable (${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf  ${SRC_FILE0}  ${SRC_FILE1}  ${SRC_FILE2} )

# Link the library to the target
target_link_libraries (${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf )

# Generate the binary file
add_custom_target (${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.bin ALL arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Obinary "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf" "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.bin" DEPENDS ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

# Generate the hex file
add_custom_target (${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.hex ALL arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Oihex "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf" "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.hex" DEPENDS ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

# Echo the size Infomation
add_custom_target (size ALL arm-none-eabi-size "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf" DEPENDS ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

# Make flash to the board by st-link
add_custom_target (flash COMMAND st-flash write ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.bin 0x8000000)

# Make clean-all
add_custom_target (clean-all COMMAND rm -rf ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*)
```

I am also using this toolchain:

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)

set(CROSS_TARGET_TRIPLET "arm-none-eabi-")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CROSS_TARGET_TRIPLET}gcc")
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "${CROSS_TARGET_TRIPLET}gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CROSS_TARGET_TRIPLET}g++")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
```

Notice how I set a custom linker script. Other than that, it's fairly strait forward.
You can find the github repo of all the files [here](https://github.com/Lasslos/hbrs-praktikum/tree/cmake/OpenRoboticBoard/UserApp/_Project/CMakeTest).

The setup works:

```
[main] Configuring project: DemoX 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/Laslo/Development/cpp/hbrs-praktikum/OpenRoboticBoard/UserApp/_Project/DemoX/toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -SC:/Users/Laslo/Development/cpp/hbrs-praktikum/OpenRoboticBoard/UserApp/_Project/DemoX -Bc:/Users/Laslo/Development/cpp/hbrs-praktikum/OpenRoboticBoard/UserApp/_Project/DemoX/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
[cmake] -- Found assembler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
[cmake] -- Configuring done (2.5s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.1s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Laslo/Development/cpp/hbrs-praktikum/OpenRoboticBoard/UserApp/_Project/DemoX/build
```

Howver, running build throws the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Laslo\Development\cpp\hbrs-praktikum\OpenRoboticBoard\UserApp\_Project\DemoX\build> cmake --build .

(compiler warings...)

[100%] Linking CXX executable bin\Target.elf
c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp\libg.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Target.elf.dir\build.make:112: bin/Target.elf] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/Target.elf.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

I did manage to remove the error and get a successful compile by adding

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -specs=nano.specs")
```

However, the compiled file then only has 128 bytes and none of my compiled code. Any idea whats going on? Here is the [linker script](https://github.com/Lasslos/hbrs-praktikum/blob/cmake/OpenRoboticBoard/UserApp/_Project/CMakeTest/stm32f4xx_gcc.ld)

I also found some source that supposedly implements this method:

```c
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file      sysmem.c
 * @author    Generated by STM32CubeIDE
 * @brief     STM32CubeIDE System Memory calls file
 *
 *            For more information about which C functions
 *            need which of these lowlevel functions
 *            please consult the newlib libc manual
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
 * in the root directory of this software component.
 * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */

/* Includes */
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * Pointer to the current high watermark of the heap usage
 */
static uint8_t *__sbrk_heap_end = NULL;

/**
 * @brief _sbrk() allocates memory to the newlib heap and is used by malloc
 *        and others from the C library
 *
 * @verbatim
 * ############################################################################
 * #  .data  #  .bss  #       newlib heap       #          MSP stack          #
 * #         #        #                         # Reserved by _Min_Stack_Size #
 * ############################################################################
 * ^-- RAM start      ^-- _end                             _estack, RAM end --^
 * @endverbatim
 *
 * This implementation starts allocating at the '_end' linker symbol
 * The '_Min_Stack_Size' linker symbol reserves a memory for the MSP stack
 * The implementation considers '_estack' linker symbol to be RAM end
 * NOTE: If the MSP stack, at any point during execution, grows larger than the
 * reserved size, please increase the '_Min_Stack_Size'.
 *
 * @param incr Memory size
 * @return Pointer to allocated memory
 */
void *_sbrk(ptrdiff_t incr)
{
  extern uint8_t _end; /* Symbol defined in the linker script */
  extern uint8_t _estack; /* Symbol defined in the linker script */
  extern uint32_t _Min_Stack_Size; /* Symbol defined in the linker script */
  const uint32_t stack_limit = (uint32_t)&_estack - (uint32_t)&_Min_Stack_Size;
  const uint8_t *max_heap = (uint8_t *)stack_limit;
  uint8_t *prev_heap_end;

  /* Initialize heap end at first call */
  if (NULL == __sbrk_heap_end)
  {
    __sbrk_heap_end = &_end;
  }

  /* Protect heap from growing into the reserved MSP stack */
  if (__sbrk_heap_end + incr > max_heap)
  {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return (void *)-1;
  }

  prev_heap_end = __sbrk_heap_end;
  __sbrk_heap_end += incr;

  return (void *)prev_heap_end;
}
```

Comment: Sure that your apparently bare metal target libs support `_sbrk`?

Comment: 70% sure. I even just found the source for the method _sbrk for this exact processer, I'll add it to the post. If the target didn't supported it, what could I do? If it does, how do I include this in my hex file?

Comment: The code you show for _sbrk assumes a specific memory layout. Does it match the target where you plan to run the program?

Comment: The code was generated for the exact chip, so yes, I'd assume so.

Comment: what did st say when you asked?